# solve recurrence relation $a(n)=2a(n-1)+1$

Tags: recurrence-relations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Solving a Recurrence Relation/Equation, is there more than 1 way to solve this?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106036/solving-a-recurrence-relation-equation-is-there-more-than-1-way-to-solve-this)

I am trying to solve following recurrence relation

$$a(n)=2a(n-1)+1\;.$$

I have divided both side by $2^n$, so get $$a(n)2^{-n}=2^{1-n}a(n-1)+2^{-n}\;.$$

After I put $n=1$ I have got $a(1)=2a(0)$, so $a(0)=1/2$, but how to continue for the general solution? I can't use formula of quadratic equation, namely
$k^2-2k-1=0$, because in this case $k_1=1+\sqrt2$ and $k_2=1-\sqrt2$, but it does not help me to find actual solution.

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/106061/12042) for three ways to solve exactly this recurrence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't deduce $a(0)$ from your recurrence.

Add $1$ on both sides to get
$$b(n)=a(n)+1=2(a(n-1)+1)$$
so that 
$$b(n)=2 b(n-1)$$

Fine continuation!

Answer (score 1):

You have to choose a(1).
You can open the formula for n=2,...,n.
You get in this way n-1 equalities. The product of all the left members of those equalities is equal to the product of all right members.
You can simplify in both products a(2) ....a(n-1).
Then you get that a(n)=2^n-1 * a(1)

Sorry, I did not see the +1 , so my answer was for a(n)=2a(n-1) 
But with the next answer it can help a little (-:.