# Explicit formula for recurrence relation $a_{n+1} = 2a_n + 1$

Tags: calculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Solving a Recurrence Relation/Equation, is there more than 1 way to solve this?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106036/solving-a-recurrence-relation-equation-is-there-more-than-1-way-to-solve-this)

How do I find an explicit formula for $a_n$ given $a_0 = 3$ and $a_{n+1} = 2a_n + 1$.  I'm guessing it's probably related to the formula for first $n$ terms of a geometric series.  Any help is appreciated

Comment: Duplicated: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/106036/23875

Answer (score 3):

Write out the first few terms. Add one to each term. Make a conjecture. Prove it by induction.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $a_{n+1}+1=2a_n+2=2(a_n+1)$. Define then $u_n=a_{n}+1$. Note that $u_{n+1}=2u_n$.