# Solving Recurrence Relations using Iteration

Tags: recurrence-relations

$$a_0 = 2; \qquad a_k=4a_{k-1}+5 ~ \forall\ k\ge 1$$

I have already tried solving for $a_1$ through $a_5$.

Comment: The second example in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/106061/12042) (‘Unwind the recurrence’) illustrates the technique; take a look at it and see if you can adapt it to solve your recurrence.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align*}
a_k - a_{k-1} & = 4a_{k-1}+5 -(4a_{k-2}+5) \\
&= 4(a_{k-1} - a_{k-2}) \\
&= 4^2(a_{k-2}-a_{k-3}) \\
& =4^{k-1}(a_1-a_0) \\
& =11\cdot 4^{k-1} \\
\Rightarrow a_k & = (a_k-a_{k-1})+(a_{k-1} - a_{k-2})+\cdots +(a_1-a_0)+a_0 \\
& = 11\cdot 4^{k-1} +11\cdot 4^{k-2} +\cdots + 11\cdot 4 + 11 + 2 \\
& = \ldots
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Using `\begin{align*}...\end{align*}` might help in greatly increasing the readability of your (otherwise good) answer. For example
$$\begin{align*}a & = b & | \cdot 2\\ 2a &= 2b\\ &=(\sin^2 x+ \cos^2 x - e^{i\pi})b\end{align*}$$

Comment: Feel free to take a look at my edit to see how to use the environment properly. (+1 btw)

Comment: Yes, but I noticed you didn't use the key features: `&` aligns the columns (The second columns here all start with `&=`) and $\backslash \backslash$ introduces a line break. You can optionally enter a third column, wich is the margin (my sample contains $|\cdot 2$ in this third column once).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to handle problems of this general type is to use the $Z$-transform, where the $Z$-transform $A(z)$ of the sequence $a_n$ is given by

$$A(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^{-n}$$

We know that the $Z$-transform of $a_{n+1}$ is given by

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n+1}z^{-n}=z^{-1}A(z)-z^{-1}a_0$$

So, let's apply the $Z$-transform to the series $a_{n+1}-4a_n=0$ with $a_0=2$.

Taking the $Z$-transform yields

$$zA(z)-za_0-4A(z)=0$$

whereupon solving for $A$ reveals

$$A(z) = a_0\frac{z}{z-4}$$

But we know that the $Z$-transform $R(z)$ of $r^n$ is $\frac{z}{z-r}$ (geometric series in $r/z$).

So, we find that $a_n$ is

$$a_n=2\, (4^n)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_k = b_k + c$. We then obtain that
$$b_{k} + c= 4b_{k-1} + 4c + 5 \implies b_k = 4b_{k-1} + 3c+5$$
Setting $c=-5/3$, we see that $b_k = 4b_{k-1} \implies b_k = 4^kb_0$. Further, we have $a_0 = b_0 - 5/3 = 2 \implies b_0 = 11/3$. Hence, we obtain
$$b_k = \dfrac{11}3 \cdot 4^k \implies a_k = \dfrac{11}3 \cdot 4^k - \dfrac53$$